# How to test Flex application using QTP 10

Tags: apache-flex, automated-tests, qtp

I'm wondering is there any way to automate testing of Flex applications using HP QTP 10?

And how much it costs (if solution exists)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of costs, but there is info out there on how QTP and Flex work together:

http://www.learnqtp.com/does-quicktest-professional-support-flashadobe-flex-applications/

http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=377517

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/testing_with_QTP_flex3.pdf

I found these through a quick google search on "qtp Flex".  Now, if you're doing weird things with custom components, you may have to create an automation delegate of your component so that it can be used with tools such as QTP (or FlexMonkey or RIATest)